# Powering Negative Vcc on Op Amp with no negative supply voltage

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, pcb, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I am making a shunt current sense resistor circuit. I will place this circuit on my main PCB board to measure the current going through all the different channels. I have a supply voltage of 12V Vcc to go into the OP37 op amp, which is used in my circuit. However, I don't have a -12V supply voltage to power the -Vcc terminal of the OP37 op amp. I know there are some IC's made by to invert a voltage, but the IC is kinda big, and I was looking for a simpler solution. I am using KiCAD to model my circuit in a schematic and LTSpice to make sure my circuit works correctly.

TLDR: How can I make my 12V supply voltage invert to power the -Vcc power supply of an op amp for use in a PCB?

Comment: If you don't need much current, there are switched capacitor inverters (from TI, for example.) That might be okay. Only you'd know. What kind of current compliance do you think you'll need for the negative rail?

Comment: I suggest you tell us why you think that you really need -12V. can't you use a good rail-to-rail OP-amp?

Comment: If you need a dual voltage power supply, and have a single voltage power supply, you have the wrong one.   Why not buy the right one?

Comment: I need enough current to power three OP37 op amps with a -12V  - Vcc. I've tried in LTSpice, and once the LTC1004A switched capacitor inverter turns on to power a single OP37's -Vcc, the negative output decreases from -12V to about -11V when powering three simultaneous op amps. Is there a way to increase this current, or is there another IC? Thanks